# Create bootable USB drive from Linux ISO

Tags: usb, startup, unix

I'd like to take a Linux ISO (e.g., CentOS, Ubuntu), and create a bootable USB drive. (It will be used for booting on a stock PC, not on the Mac). How do I go about creating such a drive using a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open *Disk Utility* (you can find it in the *Utilities* folder). Insert your USB drive, and select it in the left pane. Choose the tab "Restore" on the right side of the window, drag the image file into the "Source" field and the USB drive into the "Destination" field. Click the "Restore" button.

[image: Disk Utility Screenshot]

That should do it.

Comment: Have you seen this actually work? I get a "Restore Failure" with the error message being "Could not validate source - invalid argument". The source ISO is a bootable Linux ISO. The destination is a SanDisk USB key. Both are tested and confirmed to work.