# MacBook stops recognizing Android USB until restart

Tags: macos, usb, file-transfer, android

For years of development I've never had this issue. Today my Galaxy S7 Edge (Android 7.0) suddenly isn't detected via USB connection by my MacBook (El Capitan). AFT, adb, Unity, nothing detects it any more.

Same for both USB ports. Bought a new USB cable, didn't fix the issue. Tried killing adb server, to no avail. Restarting phone doesnt help. USB ports do work with other devices. Only solution is to restart computer. Then it's detected for a few minutes but as soon as I build my android app on Unity3D and push to phone, the phone is again not detected shortly afterwards. Would have to restart my computer after every new build.

I haven't changed anything, been doing this process all the time without problem until now. How is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried on another computer?

Comment: I currently have no access to other computers. But as the issue is temporarily fixed upon restarting computer, it is indeed a computer (rather than phone) related bug I guess

Comment: @yourmather boot into a linux live cd and test it there.  You can't eliminate that the phone may not be the issue.

Comment: @William thanks but I've never used the solution you mention. Would you mind sharing a little more info on what's that?

Comment: 1) Download ubuntu 2) follow this guide https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18314/create-bootable-usb-drive-from-linux-iso

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how this would help figuring out the issue but I'll try it if I can't find a better solution. It sounds drastic and a bit unsettling having to install a whole new operating system just to get my USB connection fixed - especially because I'm already quite tight on storage on my macbook and I guess Ubuntu would take up some more of it, so only if I find no other way.

Comment: boot a live cd not install operating system

Comment: Have you tried creating a temporary user account to see if the problem stops? That would narrow it down to something wrong with your user account settings, and not necessarily system-wide problem.

Comment: It's definitely related to Unity. In fact it gets fixed even if I just log out and log back in UNTIL I launch Unity3d again and click build. Then Unity won't find the device even though AFT found it before. And in some (not all) cases this will even make AFT not detecting the device any more. I'll try to create a new account to see if it works. Although I'm beginning to think I should move to a Unity3D forum to find out more.

Comment: Ok I found the issue, something apparently turned off in my developer settings the 'allow USB debugging' something that's been always turned on, maybe some software messed with my phone settings because I definitely didn't do it. It's still very strange though that this also interfered with the detection by ATF when it should only affect ADB normally. Anyway, good to know that this setting can spontaneously turn off under some circumstances, so put it on your check list when dealing with connection issues.